# How to access apache files in windows 10 bash

Tags: apache2, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using windows 10 bash and I have installed apache2 in that I can see my folders of installed ubuntu in : C:\Users\nilay\AppData\Local\lxss

But I am unable to see folders /var/www/html what is the solution for this I wanted to edit files inside that folder is there any way to access that folder

Answer (score 2):

I could tell you (I know how to do what you ask), but then it would cause breakage.

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/

> DO NOT, under ANY circumstances, create and/or modify Linux files
>   using Windows apps, tools, scripts, consoles, etc. Also note: Opening
>   files using some Windows tools may read-lock the opened files and/or
>   folders, preventing updates to file contents and/or metadata,
>   essentially resulting in corrupted files/folders.
>
> Creating/changing Linux files from Windows will likely result in data
>   corruption and/or damage your Linux environment requiring you to
>   uninstall & reinstall your distro!

**Note the warnings on that page in BIG RED LETTERS.**

Stop while you still can =)

You edit the files from within the bash environment , so

```
sudo nano /var/www/html/index.html
```

or what not